# How to fetch from API using useReducer and useEffect while still allowing requery

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Following [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) excellent guide I have a custom hook that will automatically refetch if the API URL changes. I want this behavior but I also want to be able to requery on demand from my components.

```
const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: initialData,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });
            try {
                const result = await axios(url);
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data });
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE' });
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [url]);

    return [state, setUrl];
};
```

If I call `setUrl` from my component, passing it the same URL twice (e.g. due to refresh button `onClicked`), it will not refetch because `useEffect` detects no change in the `URL` dependency.

What is the best way to enable my desired behavior?

Comment: To make the hook react twice to the same url, you can "consume" the url each time it is used. At the end of the useEffect, `setUrl(null)`. You will also need to guard against an empty url at the top of the useEffect, `if (!url) return;`, but that would be good practice in any case.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, you can use another state `attempt` to change everytime you call `updateUrl` method. Instead of direct exposing `setUrl` the exposing `updateUrl` will solve the issue.

```
const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
    const [attempt, setAttempt] = useState(false);
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: initialData,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });
            try {
                const result = await axios(url);
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data });
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE' });
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [url, attempt]);

    const updateUrl = useCallback((newUrl) => {
        setUrl(newUrl);
        setAttempt(!attempt);
    }, [newUrl, attempt]);

    return [state, updateUrl];
};
```

Or check whether you can simplify as below.

```
const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: initialData,
    });

    const setUrl = useCallback((url) => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });
            try {
                const result = await axios(url);
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data });
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE' });
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => setUrl(initialUrl), []);

    return [state, setUrl];
};
```